# JavaScript counter function help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I am currently working on a website similar to www.romneymakes.com.  I'd like to create a function which simulates the red banner to the right of the website.  I want to program a counter which increments every second.

I tried to work the programming out in a blank web page, but the code won't work.  I'd like to know if someone can help me.  The code I am using is pasted below.

```
function counter() {
    var per_sec = c.per_second, num_of_sec = 0, total;
    per_sec += 0.74;
    num_of_sec++;

    var seconds = Math.floor(num_of_sec / 10);
    total = per_sec * seconds;

    window.alert( total );
  }


  setInterval('counter', 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a string to setInterval, it will be evaluated. In that case, you'd have to pass `'counter()'` to call the function. But it's preferable to pass a function, rather than passing a string, so in your scenario you could simply write:

```
setInterval(counter, 1000);
```

You're also defining `num_of_sec` and `total` *within* the function, meaning they will only live for the duration of that function call. `num_of_sec` will be set to 0 every time the counter is called. Define these as global variables.

You're also setting `seconds = Math.floor(num_of_sec / 10)`  which means that `seconds` (and hence anything you multiply by it) will be 0 for the first 10 seconds. Is this intentional? If you want your counter to increase only once every 10 seconds, instead of every second, you might be better off passing `10000` rather than `1000` as the interval delay.

Comment: I intended for the counter to increase 0.74 every one second.  Does this mean that the "seconds=math.floor()" line isn't necessary and I can get rid of it?

Comment: @JaPerk14: yes, in that case, that line of code doesn't serve your purposes at all

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
setInterval(counter, 1000);
```

Also, `c` is not defined (something that you planned to pass as an argument to the function perhaps?):

```
c.per_second
```